# Python regex text to json script to grab all text between occurrences of the same word?

Tags: python, regex

Hello I'm writing a python regex parser and I'm trying to write a regex that selects the text between the word QUESTION in a large body of text.

Sample Text

```
Exam A
QUESTION 1
Blank is designed to help users.
A. baba.
B. caca.
C. sasa.
D. tyty.
Correct Answer: D
Explanation
Explanation/Reference:
QUESTION 2
can I do something?
A. No
B. Yes
Correct Answer: C
Explanation
Explanation/Reference:
QUESTION 3
What does provide?
asdasdasd


import re
import os
import sys


questions_file_text = open("questionguide.txt", "r").read()


Questions = re.findall("(?:(?!QUESTION).|[\n\r])*QUESTION",questions_file_text)
```

Thus I want to select everything including the question number until the next occurrence of question. This way I can do some text parsing to format it into json.

I can do the python I just can't seem to get my RegEx right can someone help me.

[image: MyQuestion]
This is the cloest I've gotten
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welp I'm dumb here is the answer:

```
import re
import os
import sys


questions_file_text = open("guide.txt", "r").read()


Questions = re.findall("(QUESTION([\s\S]*?)QUESTION)",questions_file_text)

print Questions
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `QUESTION([\s\S]*?)QUESTION`, you will miss every other `Question` because the next `Question` will already be consumed with the previous regex match.

You may use

```
re.findall(r"QUESTION.*?(?=QUESTION|$)",questions_file_text, re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQN7Ks/2). You may also capture various parts:

```
re.findall(r"QUESTION\s+(\w+)\s*(.*?)(?=QUESTION|$)",questions_file_text, re.S)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQN7Ks/3).

**Regex details**

- `QUESTION` - a `QUESTION` word
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=QUESTION|$)` - up to the `QUESTION` or end of string.